# query posts with custom taxonomy and wp_title

Tags: wordpress

I have a query in WordPress that pulls posts in the category "releases" that are tagged in the taxonomy "artists" with the artist's name - (which happens to be the title of this page.) It works great. UNTIL you use an artist name/page title with 3 words. So "san gabriel" works and "coyote clean up" does not. This is an older site and I used magic fields for some things, but I don't see how that could be part of the problem.

```
<?php query_posts( array(
        'category_name' => 'releases',
        'artist' => wp_title("",false),
        'showposts' => 0
        ) )?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <img alt="release image" src="<?php echo get ('release_info_release_image') ?>">

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p>there are currently no releases posted for this artist.</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Here is a picture to show there are no typos between the page title and the tagged taxonomy.

San Gabriel's page gets the post. Coyote Clean Up does not. When I change their name to "Coyote Clean" in the title and artists tag - IT WORKS... One word bands work. Two word bands work. Three word bands don't.

I can't think of any reason this would be happening.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

OK - here is is with 4 words and it IS working...

Comment: Did you also try single_post_title() instead of wp_title()? If that works we may not have to spend time figuring this out... it would also give us an idea where the error is. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/single_post_title

Comment: I just switched it out - but the same outcome. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into that a bit more.  -dw

Comment: It works for Zoos of Berlin? http://timenoplace.com/zoos-of-berlin

Comment: oh man! you are right! I didn't notice that! this makes it even more confusing! I feel like I have traced all of my steps...

Comment: this blows my whole theory!

Comment: Did you try "Coyote Clean Up" as title instead of "Coyote Clean UP"? Or did you even try strtolower( wp_title ... )? I'd probably use the latter just because, so it gets the same case as the tag, even though MySQL is case insensitive.

Comment: I changed the P to a lowercase p. No magic. the mystery continues...

Comment: Have you done any more experimentation? You say that if you change the name to just "Coyote Clean" it works... we now know Zoos of Berlin works. So might that mean Coyote Clean Awesomeness works? It's hard to find anything having only a defunct hypothesis to go on XD

Comment: Thanks - I am going to try that later today. I also think I'm going to take a look at the database and see if anything looks strange.

Comment: @calle - I have updated the photos to show the original change from the UP -> Up.  I have also changed them both to "Coyote Clean Up Up" and that worked fine...  so - that and "Coyote Clean" work fine. just not "Coyote Clean Up." If I can change them back and fourth... then I don't see how it could have to do with the data base... but I'll have to check in there I guess? Do those experiments reveal anything to you?

Comment: So for all we can tell all posts work except for Coyote Clean Up... it's strange, but not really as bad as we thought then. Honestly I don't know what to look for in the database. wp_title pretty much writes whatever's in it, and it write's it out correctly. The problem is probably in query_posts, which is a version of get_posts which is long and arduous to understand (to this level of nit-picking, one name not accepted for some reason). So idk where to go from here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh well. I only use ACF now anyways... No answer put up-votes for all the comments.